# mouse leave and mouse enter issue in jquery and click to submenu link than close to submenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI i m writing a code in my projects.

I have two issue in this code

1. now i used to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` in `jquery` if i `hover` to `li` than show to `ul` `submenu` if i `mouse leave` `li` and `submenu` than `hide` the `submenu` .
2. if **click** to `submenu` link than hide the `submebu`

My Code is this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.top-nav-head li ul li a', function(){
      $('.top-nav-head >li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('.top-nav-head >li').addClass('active');
  });
  /* ************* */
  $(document).on('mouseenter', '.top-nav-head > li > a', function(){
      $(this).next('ul').show();
  });
  $(document).on('mouseleave', '.top-nav-head > li > a ', function(){
      $('.top-nav-head > li').next('ul').hide();
  });
  /* ************* */
});
```

```css
.top-nav-head>li.active{
    background:red;
}
.top-nav-head{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
    background:blue;
    float: left;}
.top-nav-head>li{
    
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.top-nav-head>li > a{
    color: #000;
      padding: 0 10px;
      display: block;
      line-height: 40px;
      font-size: 14px;
}
.top-nav-head>li > ul{
    position: absolute;
      display: none;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 140px;
      right: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: red;
    
}
.top-nav-head>li > ul>li{
    display: block;
}
.top-nav-head>li > ul>li > a{
    display: block;
          color:@white;
          padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="top-nav-head">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Admin Module</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">link admin 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link admin 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link admin 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link admin 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link admin 5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Project Management</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul> 
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Is this what you look for: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc8L9r9o/1/ ?

Comment: @Sergio Thanks for give me answer but this code is not running in my projects i m using angular js

Comment: What has my code to do with Angular? I just changed the jQuery to make the mouseenter/mouseleave work as I think you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest caching the hidden `ul` so you can hide them all and just show what you want.

Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc8L9r9o/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $uls = $('.top-nav-head li > ul');
    $(document).on('click', '.top-nav-head li ul li a', function () {
        $('.top-nav-head >li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.top-nav-head >li').addClass('active');
    });
    /* ************* */
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.top-nav-head > li', function () {
        $uls.hide();
        $(this).find('ul').show();

    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', '.top-nav-head > li ', function () {
        $uls.hide();
    });
    /* ************* */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change jQuery code to use `mouseleave` event

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.top-nav-head > li > a', function(){
//    alert();
      $('.top-nav-head > li > ul').hide();
  });
```

Comment: sorry for this but it''s not work check to this i mouse leave than hide the submenu but i want to if i leave li and submenu ul mouse leave than hide the submebu http://jsfiddle.net/fne9d9pk/

Comment: /*$(document).on('mouseleave', '.top-nav-head > li > a', function(){
   //alert();
   $('.top-nav-head > li > ul').hide();
       
  });*/
  $(document).on('mouseleave', '.top-nav-head > li > ul', function(){
   
   //alert();
   $('.top-nav-head > li > ul').hide();
       
  });

Answer (score 0):

@rohit azad You just need to replace single line in **mouserleave** section

Instead of this

```
$('.top-nav-head > li').next('ul').hide();
```

Use this

```
$(this).next('ul').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FINAL
  $(document).on('click', '.top-nav-head li ul li a', function(){
      $('.top-nav-head >li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('.top-nav-head >li').addClass('active');
  });
  /* ************* */
  $(document).on('mouseenter', '.top-nav-head > li > a', function(){
      $(this).next('ul').show();
  });
  $(document).on('mouseleave', '.top-nav-head > li', function(e){
      //alert();

      $('.top-nav-head > li > ul').hide();



  });

  $(document).on('mouseleave', '.top-nav-head > li > ul', function(){

      //alert();
      $('.top-nav-head > li > ul').hide();

  });
```